# CSS not resizing images in certain browsers

Tags: css

I've on my site I've got two images inside their own parents divs (the full structure for each is `div a img`). The divs have fluid heights (`height: 10%;`). The images within are set to `max-height: 100%;`. The images size properly within Webkit, but every other browser seems to have problems with one or both. I've tried searching for possible solutions, but I can't even begin to imagine what the cause even *is*.

Since it's probably easier to just show you guys, here are the relevant pages and files:

- [Main page](http://millioncranes.com) (the center logo image and the "CRASH" logo at the bottom)
- [CSS](http://millioncranes.com/templates/mc_home/css/desktop.css) (the relevant divs are `.logo` and `.crash`)

Below is a breakdown of what I'm seeing. Thanks for any help!

**edit:** Never actually mentioned what the undesirable result was. In the browsers where it's broken, the images display at 100% -- not at 100% of the parent container, but at the full size of the image itself, breaking out of its container. Hope this clarifies things!

```
Browser / DIV | .logo | .crash
chrome 22     | works |  works (same results on my friend's copy of Safari)
opera 11.61   | broke |  broke
ie 9          | works |  broke
firefox 12    | works |  broke
```

Comment: See my answer below, hopefully it will help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out it using Firebug in `firefox 15.0` and got a solution, Hopefully it will work on all browsers.

**1**. Remove css rules defined for `#footer` and add those rules in `.crash` like below:

```
.crash {
    height: 10%;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 82%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**2**. Add the following rules:

```
.footerNav {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 92%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**3**. And in `.mod-languages` replace existing styles with given below:

```
.mod-languages {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 96%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**Additional Notes:**

Your HTML structure is looking like this:

```
<div class="moduletable">
    <div class="custom">
        <div id="logo">
            <a href="http://www.millioncranes.com">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So when you wrap `moduletable` with `#footer` like below:

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="moduletable">
        <div class="custom">
            <div class="crash">
                <a title="CRASH Japan" href="http://crashjapan.com">
                    <img src="/images/crashlogo.png">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    .. /*Another moduletable*/
    .. /*Another moduletable*/
</div>
```

This causing a problem. The style of `#footer` applying on all `moduletable` elements inside `#footer`. So do not need to wrap these elements inside footer. Style your elements like you have styled for `#logo`, That's it!

Hopefully it will fix your problem in all browsers.

Comment: This did indeed resolve my problem! And the explanation is GREATLY appreciated; I feel like I now have a greater idea of what happened and what can be done to prevent it in the future. The main issue remaining is that Opera still isn't liking the `max-height` attribute, it appears -- a quick Google search shows that it's a fairly common issue, though, so I'll look into it separately from here. Thanks for the help, A.K.!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I only have a chromebook here, so I can't test on any non-webkit browser, but here's my guess:

For the rendering engine to know how to apply `height: 100%` it has to know for sure the height of the container element. People have wrestled with 100% height for a long time.

First, I would make sure your `a` is `display: block` so that the `img` definitely knows how high its container is.

Then I would play around with setting explicit heights for the `img`s container elements, and see if any of those fix it - then when you know what the problem is you can find a solution. Hopefully.

Let me know how you get on.

Answer (score -1):

Not all browsers support max-height; see http://caniuse.com/#search=max-height

You don't really say what aspect of the result you don't like: what exactly is the difference between what you expect to happen and what actually happens?

Comment: The link you mentioned says "supported" for all browsers, Except "IE7 does not support "inherit" as a value on any of these properties. IE8 has some bugs with max-width/height combined with overflow: auto/scroll."

Comment: Yeah, not really sure what the point is with the caniuse link... I'd checked it before, and it mentions that just about every browser version supports it outside of IE6-8 (un-prefixed, even!).

As for what the actual result, you're right, I didn't. I'll update my post with that information. Thanks for catching that, haha.

Comment: The page is not working for me in IE8 but in firefox it works fine. In IE, it looks like it doesn't apply the stylesheet at all to that flash crane page. As to why, i have no clue...

Comment: I saw some errors and warnings in the ff console that may or may not be relevant. (oops, sorry about caniuse.com link! my mistake)  Thanks for adding the details; now maybe you have a solution.